# fgets not terminating at newline

Tags: linux, printf, popen, fgets

According to the manpages, fgets writes a stream of characters to an array until it hits a null or newline character. But when I use fgets with a popen() stream with various shell commands, and then print the resulting array with printf, the newlines are retained and the output looks the same way as though I had gone through a terminal. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fgets(3)` man page reads:

> If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

Comment: Yes, but right before that it says "Reading stops after an EOF or a newline". I took from that that the newline itself is stored, but the following characters were not.

Comment: Are you saying that you aren't using `fgets()` and `printf()` in a loop?

Comment: No, I am, and it is working like intended, I just dont know why.

Comment: Oh, and is there an easy way to make the size of the char array fgets prints to the exact size needed? If the stream has 25 characters then the array is 25 long?